# Pow и sqrt в generic math для целых чисел

Tags: c#, математика, generics

У меня есть класс вершины:

```
public class Vertex2d<T>
    where T : INumberBase<T>, INumber<T>
{
    public Vertex2d(T x, T y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public T X { get; }
    public T Y { get; }
}
```

Мне надо возвести X и Y в какую-либо степень и извлечь корень. Как это можно сделать? Есть интерфейсы `IPowerFunctions<TSelf>` и `IRootFunctions<TSelf>`, однако они не работают например для int, так что если я добавлю такие ограничение на `where` для дженерика, то не смогу создать вершину с типом int

Comment: если не `math.pow()`, то можно представить её как цикл, в которую можно передавать только абсолютное значение в качестве числа степени

Comment: math.pow работает для IPowerFunctions, так что не подходит. Конечно да, написать самому тоже выход, но мне бы хотелось воспользоваться уже готовыми решениями

Comment: и если не `math.sqrt()`, то можно представить как цикл, объявим как `n - наше число`, `eps - подкоренная степень`, далее `x0=n/2` для начального предположения, а далее в `while (true)` цикле объявим `x1=0.5*(x0+n/x0)`, высчитаем `deltaX` как абсолютное значение из `x1-x0`, проведем сравнение, если `deltaX < eps` то возвращаем `x1`, иначе `x0=x1` и повторяем операцию в цикле

Comment: ну и так-то `IPowerFunctions<TSelf>` и `IRootFunctions<TSelf>` уже депрекат, т.е. не является стандартной частью .NET Framework, что ставит под сомнение её использование на серьезных манерах

Comment: @Acinit generic math и интерфейсы от туда не деприкейтед, они вышли в 7 версии .NET, год назад. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.ipowerfunctions-1?view=net-7.0, мне нужно уже готовое решение из BCL, а не самостоятельно писать руками, их слишком много чтобы переносить из System.Math в собственный костыль

Comment: ошибся, полагаю, но я наткнулся на обсуждение данной проблемы на [гитхабе](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/85707), говорится что **Да, помимо функций преобразования, мы обычно следуем принципу T-in, T-out. Поэтому, если вы принимаете файл int, вы должны вернуть файл int. Это позволяет избежать ряда проблем, которые могут возникнуть из-за разрешения перегрузки и других критических изменений или неясностей, которые могут возникнуть из-за будущих версий.**

Comment: Поэтому есть некоторое убеждение и принуждение использовать `double` тип для подобных инструкций

Comment: @Acinit да, тоже наткнулся на это же ишью, эх жаль. Видимо не обойтись без костылей..

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению нельзя сделать класс который бы работал и под целые числа, и под числа с запятой. Это объясняется [вот тут](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/85707#issuecomment-1533044391), единственный выход чтобы пользоваться всеми фичами вроде извлечения корня/возведения в степень - использовать интерфейс `IBinaryFloatingPointIeee754`. Я изменил ограничения для дженерика следующим образом:

```
public class Vertex2<T> : IComparable<Vertex2<T>>, IEquatable<Vertex2<T>>
   where T: IBinaryFloatingPointIeee754<T>
{
    public Vertex2d(T x, T y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public T X { get; }
    public T Y { get; }
}
```